# System.TypeException: Invalid date:05/05/2013

Tags: exception, date

i just executed these lines in anonymous block and got this exception. Any suggestions?

```
Date dt;
dt = Date.valueOf('05/05/2013');
System.debug(dt);
```

> System.TypeException: Invalid date: 05/05/2013

Comment: Try like this i think its works                          String dte = '5/05/2013';
String[] dst = dte.split('\');
String stdate1  = dst [2]+'-'+dst [1]+'-'+dst [0];
Date de = Date.valueOf(stdate1);
System.debug('DATEFORMAT'+de);

Comment: Use **Date.parse** instead of **Date.valueOf**.

Answer (score 5):

I useually try and keep dates in the yyyy-MM-dd format as this is more widely accepted in development.

Your code becomes:

```
Date dt;
dt = Date.valueOf('2013-05-05');
System.debug(dt);
```

and runs successfully.

Comment: From docs for Date.valueOf "The specified string should use the standard date format “yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss” in the local time zone."

Comment: Thanks @Richard. I tried to use format which salesforce used to display the date fields in the related list.

Comment: Try date.parse then as this will take the date format as you have it. You may get problems with users locale - just something to bear in mind...

Answer (score 2):

What's your user's locale? Check against http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=admin_supported_locales.htm. You might need dots or hyphens...

Generally it's safest to use `Date.newInstance(2012, 12,31);` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Please use below code, as I have also faced the issue in one of my project.

```
Date dt;
String strDate = '05/05/2013';

dt = Date.valueOf(strDate.replace('/','-'));
System.debug(dt);
```

Hope this will help you.